# Shortening for AngularJS in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular has `ng` shortening for directives in markup, but how can I use that in js code. I mean when I write `angular.isArray` I'd prefer to write `ng.isArray` (as we do with jQuery ($), or Underscore (_)). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `var ng = angular;` as a global variable, like JB Nizet suggested.

If you fear a conflict and prefer not to put anything in the global scope, you can wrap your code inside a Self-Executing Anonymous Function (closure) like this:

```
(function (ng) {
    // declare a module
    var myAppModule = ng.module('myApp', []);

    // configure myAppModule.
    // ...

})(angular);
```

Answer (score 3):

Define the following global variable:

```
var ng = angular;
```